# Square root of $-i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am stuck on the problem as the solutions given at two places do not either concur or or not understandable by me.

The non concurring answer ([here, pg #12](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~marshall/book04-1.ps)) states: one root is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

I feel my approach will yield as follows:

$x^2 +i = 0 \implies x = (-i)^{1/2} \implies$ modulus = $1$, and by de-Moivre's formula with angle $= -\pi/2$, i.e. $-i = 1.(\cos(-\pi/2) + i.\sin(-\pi/2))$.
 => $x_1 = 1.(\cos(-\pi/4) + i.\sin(-\pi/4))$

But, in fourth quadrant the cosine is positive, so one (particular) root is : $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, and the other is diametrically opposite :$-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, that is found by adding $\pi (= n2\pi/m = n^{'}\pi/m)$ to the original answer, i.e. $x_2 = 1.(\cos(3\pi/4) + i.\sin(3\pi/4)) \implies x_2 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.

The not understandable answer is given [at wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a7d8ae4569120b5bec12e7b6e9648b86) that although gels with me in terms of geometric location of the points, yet the answer of $\pm(-1)^{3/4}$ confuses me totally.

Comment: The wolframalpha solution is the same as yours

Comment: @JohnDoe But not able to see the expression form to be so.

Comment: $(-1)^{3/2} = -(-1)^{1/2} = -i$. Therefore $(-1)^{3/4} = (-i)^{1/2}$

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for that.

Comment: @jiten It doesn't tell you much in that it isn't in polar form, and isn't written as $x+iy$. But it is correct. If you define the branch of $f(z)=z^{\frac14}$ to be $z^{\frac14}=e^{\frac14 \log(|z|)+\frac i4\arg(z)}$, then $$(-1)^\frac34=(e^{\frac i4\cdot \pi})^3=e^{\frac34i\pi}=-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac1{\sqrt2}$$ as required. (although I suspect this is more advanced than you're expected to do for your work)

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks a lot for giving a better view. If possible, kindly state in detail or please give some reference terms to google for regarding the "branch of $z^\frac{1}{4}$". Else, please refer to some source.

Comment: Are you aware of branch cuts? The nth root functions has n branches for each root

Comment: @Dylan Read this as cursory in complex analysis. So, these are linked topics! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your geometric reasoning is completely correct: the roots must be in the second and fourth quadrants.

The answer $-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} -i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ must therefore be wrong. We can also check that it is wrong by multiplying it out: $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} -i\frac{1}{\sqrt2})(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} -i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) = \frac{1}{2} + 2i\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = i \neq -i$. On the other hand, multiplying out your two answers will indeed give $-i$.

$\pm(-1)^\frac{3}{4}$ works too, since $(\pm(-1)^\frac{3}{4})^2 = (-1)^\frac{3}{2} = ((-1)^\frac{1}{2})^3 = i^3 = -i$. However, it's not as enlightening in terms of where on the complex plane those points actually are.

Comment: The books states it as 'one of the roots', so the other must be having both real & imaginary parts positive, leading to the same value ($-i$), so that's not the criteria. But, it must a good idea, may be in some other situation for cross-checking, but not valid here.

Comment: @jiten Your link isn't working for me, so I haven't seen the book... By "both real & imaginary parts are positive," I assume you mean $\frac{1}{\sqrt2} + i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. But if you square this, you _also_ get $i$, not $-i$...

Comment: I hoped that both roots need to be multiplied, sorry as my logic is wrong. Actually, never thought like that before, and your comment made it clear that you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative Method:** Let $z=x+iy$ and $c=a+ib$. Consider the equation $z^2=c$. which is $x^2-y^2+2ixy=a+ib$. Solve for $x$ and $y$. We get the desired result.

Here, $x^2-y^2=0,2xy=-1.\implies y=-x, 2x^2=1$ Hence $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}-i \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ and $z= -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+i \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: There is also the solution $y=x$, which leads to $2x^2=-1\implies x\not\in\Bbb R$ which is a contradiction to the initial assumption that $x,y,a,b\in\Bbb R$. (I mention for completeness)

Comment: yes. you are correct.

Comment: This is an obvious way to solve, but new to me. Thanks.

Comment: :) You are welcome